# I need PowerShell script that can look for particular word in the txtfiles and add “00” at the beginning of the line

Tags: windows, shell, powershell

Example:

```
bank of america                                  Page
chase bank                                       count
alli bank                                        Page
```

Output:

```
00 bank of america                                Page
   chase bank                                     count
00 ally bank                                      Page
```

PowerShell script needs to look for word “page” and add “00” at the beginning of the line.

My script is working and I can see the result in cmd output window but it's not updating .txt file inside the user folder.

```
powershell -command "foreach($ln in cat 'c:\users*.txt'){if($ln -match 'page'){write-host '00'$ln}}"
```

Please let me know what I need to add to the script to be able to update `c:\users*.txt` files. I have multiple txt files inside the users folder, so when I run the script they all need to get updated inside user folder but with my script, it's not happening.

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their existing programming code. Edit your Q to show sample inputs/outputs and your best attempt at code. Sorry, but requests for tutorials, research, tools, recommendations, libraries, and code are off-topic.  ***Please*** read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck

Comment: I already have written the code and it working just not updating original files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making the string replacements but you're not setting the contents of the original file after the processing. Grab each file individually and then set the contents.

```
powershell -command "(Get-ChildItem C:\users*.txt).FullName | ForEach-Object {(Get-Content $_) | ForEach-Object {if($_ -match 'page') { return '00' + $_} else {return $_}} | Set-Content $_ }"
```